# Sed extract substring

Tags: awk, sed

I'm trying to extract table name from sql query with sed.

So far I have:

```
 echo 'select * from marketo.leads limit 1;' | sed -n 's/.*from \(.*\) .*/\1/p'
```

the result:
`marketo.leads limit`

Somehow next word also get to capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is that regular expressions are greedy, so `.*` tries to swallow as much it can. In this case, it matches `marketo.leads limit`, with the rest of the line matching `1;` (space, one, semicolon).

Try

```
echo 'select * from marketo.leads limit 1;' | sed -n 's/.*from \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/p'
```

Of course this is not a perfect solution – what if the line is

```
select * from ['My funny table'] limit 1:
```

Answer (score 1):

grep with `-P` and `-o` option:

```
grep -Po '.*from +\K\S*'
```

Comment: This answer is the most appropriate if you ask me, but isn’t compatible with `macOS` or `BSD`.

Comment: @Mihir zero experience with MAC. but gnu grep can be installed on mac right?